# How do I incorporate decimals into calculator in objective c?

Tags: ios, decimal, calculator

The following is my app made in Xcode with Objective C. This is ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    valueString = @"";
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)tappedClear:(id)sender
{
    total = 0;
    valueString = @"";
    label.text = @"0";
}
-(IBAction)tappedNumber:(UIButton*)btn
{
    int num = btn.tag;
    if (num == 0 && total == 0) {
        return;
    }
    if (lastButtonWasMade) {
        lastButtonWasMade = false;
        valueString = @"";
    }
    NSString *numAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",num];
    valueString = [valueString stringByAppendingString:numAsString];
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    NSNumber *n = [formatter numberFromString:valueString];
    label.text = [formatter stringFromNumber:n];
    if (total == 0) {
        total = [valueString intValue];
    }
}
-(IBAction)tappedPlus:(id)sender
{
    [self setMode:1];
}
-(IBAction)tappedMinues:(id)sender
{
    [self setMode:-1];
}
-(IBAction)tappedEquals:(id)sender
{
    if (mode == 0) {
        return;
    }
    if (mode == 1) {
        total +=[valueString intValue];
    }
    if (mode == -1) {
        total -=[valueString intValue];
    }
    if (mode == 2) {
        total *=[valueString intValue];
    }
    if (mode == 1/2) {
        total /=[valueString intValue];
    }
    if (mode == 10) {
        total *=[valueString intValue];
    }
    valueString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",total];
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    NSNumber *n = [formatter numberFromString:valueString];
    label.text = [formatter stringFromNumber:n];
    mode = 0;

}
-(IBAction)tappedMultiply:(id)sender
{
    [self setMode:2];
}
-(IBAction)tappedDivide:(id)sender
{
    [self setMode:1/2];
}    
-(IBAction)tappedDecimal:(id)sender
{

}
-(IBAction)tappedPercent:(id)sender
{
    [self setMode:10];
}

-(void)setMode:(int)m
{
    if (total == 0) {
        return;
    }
    mode = m;
    lastButtonWasMade = true;
    total = [valueString intValue];
}

@end
```

The following is my ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    int total;
    int mode;
    NSString *valueString;
    IBOutlet UILabel *label;
BOOL lastButtonWasMade;
}
-(IBAction)tappedClear:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)tappedNumber:(UIButton*)btn;
-(IBAction)tappedPlus:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)tappedMinues:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)tappedEquals:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)tappedMultiply:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)tappedDivide:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)tappedDecimal:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)tappedPercent:(id)sender;

@end
```

I have each button tagged in Main.storyboard to get rid of excess code. 
Basically, I would like to have a decimal button that works, a percentage button that works, and a division button that works. I also want to clear the screen when a new digit is entered after the equal sign is pressed.

I'd import pictures but I have no reputation.a

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so please tag it as so.

Comment: No, DO NOT use the homework tag. @AshleyMills It's gone for a reason.

Comment: And I would like to have someone doing my homework!

Comment: It actually is not a homework question. I am building this app on my own time for fun